# Alarm reset firing onReceive method multiple times

Tags: android

I've receiver that set alarm at multiple time. When I boot my device, I'm using boot receiver and calling service to reset alarm that was previously set. Suppose, I set three alarm but **onRecieve()** is getting triggered multiple times.

below my code used in service to reset alarm:

```
   sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(UpdateService.this,nofify_id,
                        intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
                {
                    am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
                }
                else  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,          calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
                }

                else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT )
                {
                    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,     calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
                }
```

This is receiver code that will be called

```
public class OneShotAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
// calling multiple times`enter code here`

}

}
```

Comment: From the document "If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately, with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the trigger time is relative to the repeat interval." , In your case it looks like the extra onReceive() call are from  you have set alarm previously (calendar.getTimeInMillis()) that is being triggered after reboot.